# Is there a way to filter by a calculated value without wrapping it in another select?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a simple query like

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
FROM Docs 
WHERE Name like '%something%' OR Value like '%something%'
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

The table Docs has a record for each product that goes out of an inventory as such:

```
ID: the id of the document through which the product was released from the inventory (for example an invoice or a delivery note)  
Name: the name of the document  
qty: the number of units that were released  
price: the unit price of the product in said inventory
```

(the actual table is a lot more complex than that but I simplified it a lot for clarity)

As you can see the query I've posted is a blanket search. I want to list all the documents with their ID, name and total value whose name or value is like some user input. However I can't actually use the Value column in the WHERE clause.

I could wrap it in another `select * FROM ()` and do the search on that. BUT the query I have to work with is a lot more complex and changing it in that way would be a whole lot of trouble.

IS there any way to avoid wrapping the whole query if I want to do this kind of search?

Comment: Do you understand that the filtering of the name would impact the value of the sum?

Comment: Yeah I gotta change the query a bit, I forgot the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will HAVING do the same thing?

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
FROM Docs
HAVING Value like '%something%' OR Name like '%something%'
```

Comment: That's actually a really good Idea. I wouldn't have to change the way in which the search portion of the query is computed, just some of the names of the search columns. I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I removed the blanket search section of the query from the WHERE clause to a newly added HAVING clause. It tests out a bit slower but it works nicely and was easy to implement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
FROM Docs 
having Value like '%something%' or Name like '%something%'
```

Comment: using Having will eliminate some valid rows (mainly those where name is like someting but value isn't)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to make "select from select" `UNION` can help you:

```
(SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
FROM Docs 
WHERE Name like '%something%')
UNION
(SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
FROM Docs 
HAVING SUM(qty * price) like '%something%')
```

Comment: While this does avoid select from select, it brings much of the same problems. The query I have to work on is huge and each part of it is computed separately depending on a lot of factors, changing the select into a union would mean me working a whole lot on changing all of the query-computing functions which is what i'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT ID, Name, SUM(qty * price) as Value
> FROM Docs 
> WHERE Name like '%something%' OR Value like '%something%'
> GROUP BY ID, Name
> ```

Only problem with this query is that MySQL does not allow use of aliases in WHERE clause.

So you can simple repeat the calculation in the WHERE clause, and it should work:

```
WHERE Name like '%something%' OR SUM(qty * price) like '%something%'
```

Don't worry about having the same calculation twice in your query - the query optimizer should recognize that and still calculate the value only once.

(And btw., using LIKE on a numerical value seems kinda strange - other comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, `>` might be more appropriate.)

Comment: I tried using the calculation in the where clause but that results in an error. Also the only reason for using the like is maintaining homogenity for the sake of our clients who don't know the difference between an integer and a string field and want the blanket search to work the same for every field. Also helps when the client wants to find that one document/client/whatever that had some string of digits in their value/balance. We have more specific searches where we use <, > and = but this is a general blanket search.